# How to Pass object from sub activity to main activity?

Tags: android

From ActivityA I'm starting ActivityB.
In ActivityB I'm creating a new Serializable object.
After the object has been created I want to **close** ActivityB and pass the new object to ActivityA.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

start Activity B with `startActivityForResult()`.
In activity B, when the object is created create an Intent to pack the object in:

```
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra("result", object);
setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
```

Then you will receive that intent in the `onActivityResult()` method of Activity A, where you can extract it like so:

```
data.getSerializableExtra("result");
```

Comment: I think you should implement Parcelable for *object* instead. After that, you can pass your *object* as a primitive type via Intent.

Answer (score 2):

Start the Activity B using **startActivityForResult** method.

When you finish creating object call **setResult** in Activity B. Set Your Data in Intent. You don't need to finish this.

Override function **onActivityResult** in Activity A. This will be called when you call **setResult** in Activity B. You can receive the data from Intent passed from Activity B.

**But most of the time, you need separate Activities if only you have different screens with different tasks. Otherwise accomplish the task within the same Activity.** **(A Good and Standard Practice).**

Answer (score 0):

after the object is created, create an intent object, put that object to that intent and then start activity A. In the Activity A's onRestart() get that intent and from that intent get that object.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you doing that? If you're using activity B only for creating new object, you can do it in a plain simple java class. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It could happen that the user creates the object in Activity B by setting some settings or something?